# Plot/graph this csv file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm completely new to Python and decided to learn it for our machine learning course as an engineer, however I'm having difficulties in retrieving values from my csv file which looks like the following:

[image]

Where I want to retrieve my B,C, and D values (retrieved from a Gravity sensor).

Code I've tried in my Jupyter Notebook:

```py
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
data_file = np.genfromtxt("Gravity.csv", delimiter="", names=["A","B","C","D"])
    
plt.plot(data_file['A'], data_file['B'],data_file['C'],data_file['D'])    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Empty brackets are concrete values that you have just removed for the shake of privacy or are they just empty brackets denoting null values?

Comment: For the sake of privacy(laziness of inserting an image, which I just inserted), they are not actually empty and contain values such as 0.123123, 0.12121, 9.8.

Comment: The image I just inserted is from a csv file (collected using an android app, stored as csv file, and displayed above in excel)

Comment: What is exactly the problem?do you get any error message?your code looks ok assuming `data_file` is the csv you posted the screenshot of

Comment: My problem is that it doesn't actually plot anything for me, while the row itself gives no real error. And yes, it is the csv from the screenshot called Gravity.csv.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the delimiter. try this:  `delimiter=""`  --> `delimiter=","`

Comment: I added that, however it didn't change anything for me (sadly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your file to this format

```
A,B,C,D

0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.8

0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1

0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1
```

and used the following code

```
import pandas as pd
values= pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
```

this works

[image]

Comment: How would I do if I want to use this in my regular format? Currently I've loaded my csv file using pandas and it worked to just write values and it prints out the values. But when I print it it doesn't work since it can't find they keyword 'A'.

Comment: What is your regular format? "... and it prints out the values. But when I print it it doesn't work...". What do you mean?

Comment: My regular format is the one seen in the print above. And with print I mean plot (bad choice of words on my part); for instance, I can see that i get all values correctly when simply writing "values". But I never manage to "plot" the graph because I get the error that it cannot find the keyword for, for example, 'A'.

Comment: Does your csv file have headers? What does `<name of your df>.keys` produce? Is it A,B,C? What is the command you're using to plot? You can only get a KeyError if you're specifying something that's not a header. I you find this answer or any of these comments helpful please consider upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `np.genfromtxt` is also encoding the index column (values from 1 to 9) and also the header so that when you think you are selecting column `'B'` you are actually selecting column `A` and so on.

this should work

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
data_file = np.genfromtxt("Gravity.csv", delimiter=",", names=["index", "A","B","C","D"], skip_header=1)
    
plt.plot(data_file['B'],data_file['C'],data_file['D'])    
plt.show()
```

and a working example of the same concept but with artificial data

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[4,5,6], 'd':[7,8,9]})
data.to_csv('./data.csv')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('./data.csv', delimiter=",", names=["index", "A","B","C","D"], skip_header=1)
plt.plot(data2['B'], data2['C'], data2['D'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: For the data_file = np.genfromtxt line of your code I got the following error: ValueError, could not assign tuple of length 4 to  structure with 5 fields.

Comment: can you please run `print(data_file['A'])` after you load it successfully through your code?what is the print output?

Comment: The print output is correct it seems like. Since it's 1.6009, 1.6009 etc. However, I could not add "index" at the front, but since I got the correct value from A, I guess I don't need "index" at front. Strange that it won't show my plot in jupyter notebook.

Comment: does my other example work?if not you might be facing a notebook configuration problem maybe?

Comment: Regarding your other example with artificial data it says that numpy does not have any attribute called DataFrame and "to_csv".

Answer (score -1):

You have four columns in your data (`A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`) but you're only supplying three column names (`B`, `C`, and `D`). So it's linking name `B` to column `A` in the data and so on. Column `D` in the data is ignored like this so you need to designate four names so that each column can be queried as you expect.

Additionally, columnar data is handled well using `pandas`.

```py
import pandas as pd
    
data_file = pd.read_csv("Gravity.csv", names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Comment: I did try to add "A" as well. However, it didn't plot anything for me for some reason? Not sure if I need to add the first column as well? (where the row numbers are)

Comment: this does not make sense. the following code is working perfectly fine 

`data2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[4,5,6], 'd':[7,8,9]})`

`plt.plot(data2['b'], data2['c'], data2['d'])`

`plt.show()`

Comment: What are you trying to plot (i.e. what information would you like to get out of the graph)?

Comment: The acceleration from X and Y (B and C) as well as the gravity from D.

Comment: @JacoSolari is that not a different method though? I agree it works with `pandas` but the original method uses `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: @RobinSvensson you're trying to plot X's acceleration against Y's acceleration and gravity? What are your axes and what kind of plot is this? Essentially I'm wondering what relationship you want to show between the three values; that would help give direction on what plotting method to pursue.

Comment: I want to show the relation of gravity to the acceleration (where the phone in this case just lays still on the table and the acceleration is around 0, and gravity is 9.8).